# Anatomy of a Cyber exercise and SOC

Tags: cyber-warfare, soc

What exactly entails an incident response exercise (like a Red/Tiger team excercise)? How does it add value to a security operations center? Is there any good resource I can read up on how to set up a 24x7 security operations center SOC? I am also looking at engaging expertise on SOC for my company. What are some of the basic requirement that I should look for when engaging external vendor to help me plan how the SOC should be set up? thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a "cyber" excercise?

Comment: I think dorothy meant business games, to train for serious events. There are many ressources out the in the web on "how to set up a soc". On of the hits from a search engine: http://www.mcafee.com/ca/resources/white-papers/foundstone/wp-creating-maintaining-soc.pdf

Comment: http://www.mitre.org/publications/all/ten-strategies-of-a-world-class-cybersecurity-operations-center